# How to remove automatic numbering of figure in LaTex?

Tags: latex

I would like the caption of my figure to be "Figure A". Is there a way to remove the automatic numbering of the figures?

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure A}
\centering
 \caption{Title}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{test.png}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With the code above, the caption is "Figure A 1".

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two quick hacks, either you can temporarily remove the number or you can latex do the numbering with capital letters:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure A}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{}
\centering
\caption{Title}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Alph{figure}}
\centering
\caption{Title}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```